# Read a JSON array from a cell and write part of the last object to another cell in the same row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to pull some information from a JSON array in a Google Sheet and take part of that info and copy it into two columns beside it.

The data I want is in Column L of my sheet (starting in row 2) and in the format:

`[{"id": "XX:123456", "timestamp": "2020-01-27T19:25:51.303"}, {"id": "XX:654321", "timestamp": "2020-01-27T19:40:37.06"}]`

Currently my script is as follows:

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("parsed");
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastRow = dataRange.getLastRow();



function parseData() {
   for (var row=2; row<lastRow; row++) 
   {
      var parseRange = sheet.getRange(row,12,5,1)
      var json = JSON.parse(parseRange.getValue());
      var lastObject = json.length-1;
      var org = json[lastObject];
      var orgID = org.id;
      var timestamp = org.timestamp;

      sheet.getRange(row, 13).setValue(orgID);
      sheet.getRange(row, 14).setValue(timestamp);
   }
}
```

This is very time consuming to process as it is reading and writing each row one by one. I had assumed the JSON array was already in sequential order, but having checked it appears to be random. What I ideally would like to do is sort the array by timestamp first, then take the object with the latest timestamp and write that data to column M and N, and to do this in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Use `getValues()` and `setValues()` to batch up operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

#### Snippet:

```
let parseRange = sheet.getRange(1+1,12,lastRow-1,1);//col L
let values = parseRange.getValues();
let out = values.map(([row])=>{
  let {id, timestamp} = JSON.parse(row).pop();
  return [id, timestamp];
});
sheet.getRange(1+1, 13, lastRow-1, 2).setValues(out);
```

Comment: Thanks, Google Apps Script doesn't seem to be playing nicely with this. I'm getting a  'Missing ; before statement' error on the first line, if I amend 'let' to 'var' my error then becomes a Syntax error on the values.map line

Comment: @rory Upgrade to v8. You need to edit the manifest file to change runtime version. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Brilliant that has resolved that issue. Any ideas on how I can sort the data in each individual row to only select the orgId and timestamp for the latest timestamp?

Comment: @rory Kindly ask a new question